# Accessing sqlite database data in Ionic 2 as per demand rather than loading it in memory

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I am developing an application that has a pre-populated database which acts as a master database. I am very new to Ionic app development. My goal is to fetch only so much data that I need at the time rather than having whole data loaded in memory all the time. The size of my db file is 60mb. Am I missing something? Is it possible? Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What database plugin are you using, if any?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have used sql.js which loads all the data in memory which is working fine when I run the application on browser with ionic serve command. I read today about pouchDB with sqlite but that I think also loads all the data in memory. Can you please help? Is it even possible to achieve what I need?

Comment: Use a SQLite plugin instead. sql.js is SQLite compiled to JS, which is almost certainly not what you need nor what you want. I suggest the following plugin: https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext. I've used it with good success, and it will be much more memory efficient.

Comment: Okay thanks. Reading the documentation for cordova-sqlite-ext. Don't mind me for asking but does the db variable after the opening the connection with openDatabase() function contains the whole database in memory? or is it just the connection object that fetches the data as I query? I can not test right away as they are saying sqlite only runs on emulator/device.

Comment: Think of the `db` variable as a handle to the database. The entire contents of the database are not loaded in memory. However, you should be careful about the size of your result sets. If you need to return a large number of rows are a large amount of data, consider requesting fewer rows over multiple requests.

Comment: ohh very nice. This is exactly what I have been looking for. Let me learn more about it. I hope I will be able use it and close this topic. :) thanks